# R: Shiny dateRangeInput format

Tags: r, date, shiny

I am using the packet shiny for R and I implemented a dateRangeInput in my **ui.R:**

```
   dateRangeInput("date", "Date range:",
                       start  = "2013-05-15",
                       end    = "2013-10-01",
                       min    = "2013-05-15",
                       max    = "2013-10-01",
                       format = "dd/mm/yy",
                       separator = " - ")
```

If I display the selected min and max values, i get the following (weird) output:

**Min date value:**

```
renderText({(input$date[1])})
```

Output:

```
 15840
```

**Max date value:**

```
renderText({(input$date[2])})
```

Output:

```
15979
```

Why do I get these numbers in the output and not the selected ate from the ui.R itself: 2013-05-15 and 2013-10-01 ? And how can I transform it to such a format? as.Date does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The actual value is days since the unix epoch, use `format(input$date[1])`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some thing like this

```
observe({
x <- format(input$date[1])

  cat(x,file="/home/indraneel/temp/r1outfile.txt",append=TRUE)

})
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case for dateRangeInput selector, the results were strings

```
date_start <- input$dateRangeInput_name_one[1]
date_end <- input$dateRangeInput_name_one[2]
```

BTW: If you 'date' is integer you can convert it to 'date' by using the following code:

```
 date_start_date <- as.Date(date_start, origin = "1970-01-01")
 date_end_date <- as.Date(date_end, origin = "1970-01-01")
```