# R Shiny: How to take dates from "Date Range", plug them into Quandl, and use the resulting data to generate a graph

Tags: r, shiny, quandl

I started building my first shiny app and it ended up being more complicated than expected (learning!). Unfortunately, I've managed to Google-fu a ton of little errors into a situation in which there are no errors, it just returns a blank graph.

The Code: (server)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Quandl)
library(methods)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
# see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834778/r-shiny-daterangeinput-format)

start_date2<-reactive({format(input$date_range[1])})
end_date2<-reactive({format(input$date_range[2])})

psuedonym<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                      Value=integer(),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

psuedonym<-reactive({Quandl("ZILL/Z94550_A", start_date2, end_date2, type="raw")})

output$qplot<-renderPlot({reactive({plot(psuedonym$Date, psuedonym$Value)})})
})
```

(ui)

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("My Shiny App"),

    sidebarLayout(position="right", 
        sidebarPanel(
        plotOutput("qplot")
        ),
    mainPanel(dateRangeInput("date_range", 
        label=h3("Date Range"), start="2010-01-01", end="2015-01-01",
    )
))))
```

What I want: I want the user to be able to input dates in the Date Range, input those variables into the Quandl code (https://www.quandl.com/help/r), and then pull that data for them and generate a simple graph. Later on I'd like to add the ability to define the zip code and the variables. This, for example, works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Quandl)
library(methods)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    start_date="2010-01-01"
    end_date="2015-01-01"
    psuedonym=Quandl("ZILL/Z90001_A", start_date, end_date, type="raw")
    output$qplot<-renderPlot({plot(psuedonym)})
```

What I think is going wrong: This([R: error in qplot from ggplot2: argument "env" is missing, with no default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708188/r-error-in-qplot-from-ggplot2-argument-env-is-missing-with-no-default)) and a previous error message makes me think that something has gone wrong with the data frame, that it's not getting the Quandl data somehow.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you misunderstand how shiny works.

Have a look this tutorial.
http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson4/

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(dateRangeInput("date_range", label=h3("Date Range"),start="2010-01-01", end="2015-01-01")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("qPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$qPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    psuedonym<-Quandl("ZILL/Z94550_A", input$date_range[1], input$date_range[2], type="raw")
    plot(psuedonym)
  }) 
}
)
```